# PowerMocking static does not return expected object

Tags: mockito, powermock

I have a problem mocking `Calendar.getInstance()`. As you now this method returns a Calendar - the object I am mocking.

Right now my code looks like this:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Calendar.class)
public class SurveillanceDatabaseTest {
    @Test
    public void testFailingDatabase() throws Exception {
        mockStatic(Calendar.class);
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
        when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenReturn(calendar);
        final Surveillance surveillance = new Surveillance();
        surveillance.checkDatabase();
   }
}
```

`Calendar.getInstance()` gets called various times in `surveillance.checkDatabase()` and every time it is a new object and not the expected mock of Calendar.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In @PrepareForTest annotation You have to put class, that uses static mocked class, not a class that is static mocked. In your case should be @PrepareForTest(Surveillance.class) instead of @PrepareForTest(Calendar.class).

Comment: @DominikKunicki convert it to answer, this one is correct, just tested...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to add the target test class in the PrepareForTest tag: 
**@PrepareForTest({ Calendar.class, Surveillance.class })**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ Calendar.class, Surveillance.class })
public class SurveillanceDatabaseTest {
    @Test
    public void testFailingDatabase() throws Exception {
        mockStatic(Calendar.class);
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
        when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenReturn(calendar);
        final Surveillance surveillance = new Surveillance();
        surveillance.checkDatabase();
   }
}
```

Even Tom Tresansky's example above will need it if we move the Surveillance class to somewhere outside MockCalendarTest class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're doing everything right.  For instance, this test below passes, proving that the `Calendar` returned by `Calendar#getInstance()` is in fact the one you set up with the static mocking.

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.*;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Calendar.class)
public class MockCalendarTest {
    @Test
    public void testFailingDatabase() {
        mockStatic(Calendar.class);

        final Calendar testCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        testCalendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
        when(Calendar.getInstance()).thenReturn(testCalendar);

        final Surveillance surveillance = new Surveillance();
        final Calendar resultCalendar = surveillance.checkDatabase();

        assertTrue(testCalendar == resultCalendar);
   }

    public static class Surveillance {
      public Calendar checkDatabase() {
        return Calendar.getInstance();
      }
    }
}
```

Perhaps post the relevant parts of the `Surveillance` class so we can see how it's trying to get a new `Calendar` and assess why it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as familiar with the `when(object.call()).andReturn(response);` but I'm assuming it works the same way as `expect.(object.call()).andReturn(response);`.  If that is the case, then it looks like all you are missing a replay of the class `PowerMock.replay(Calendar.class)` and you are trying to do a full static mock instead of a partial static mock.  This should resolve your issue.

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Calendar.class)
public class SurveillanceDatabaseTest {
    @Test
    public void testFailingDatabase() throws Exception {

        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);

        PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(Calendar.class, "getInstance");  //Mock Static Partial
        expect(Calendar.getInstance()).andReturn(calendar);
        PowerMock.replay(Calendar.class);  // note the replay of the Class!

        final Surveillance surveillance = new Surveillance();
        surveillance.checkDatabase();

        //Whatever tests you need to do here
   }
}
```