# How to mock a certain method while doing junit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

Below is my method which gives me the date of either recent `Monday` or recent `Thursday` in the format of `YYYYMMDD`.

Today is Saturday, so it should return date for Thursday in the format of `YYYYMMDD` so it will be - `2014027`

```
public static String getDate() {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    try {
        int dow = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        switch (dow) {
        case Calendar.THURSDAY:
        case Calendar.FRIDAY:
        case Calendar.SATURDAY:
        case Calendar.SUNDAY:
        while (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.THURSDAY) {
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        }
        break;
        case Calendar.MONDAY:
        case Calendar.TUESDAY:
        case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
        while (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.MONDAY) {
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        }
        break;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // log error
    }

    return toDateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

So my question is, how do I mock the `Calendar getInstance` method so that I can easily junit `getDate` method? I have never mocked it before so I am facing some problem?

Can anyone provide a simple example if possible on my example?

Comment: I suggest you to read about [easymock](http://easymock.org/)

Comment: [mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) is another mocking framework

Comment: @xp500:Can you provide an example if possible basis on my code base by which I will be able to understand better? Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you're unit testing `getDate()`, you shouldn't be mocking it. Do you want to mock the `Calendar` instance?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Yes I guess you are right.. I shouldn't be mocking `getDate`. It should be calendar instance.. Can you provide an example basis on my code? It will help me to understand better..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this was my code I would extract the Calendar variable into another method, overloading the method so that there is one version that takes the Calendar as a parameter and one version with no arguments, like this:

```
public static String getDate() {
    return getDate(Calendar.getInstance());
}

public static String getDate(Calendar cal} {
// your example code
}
```

This way you can write tests exercising your logic in getDate without having to use any mocks.
If you really want to cover the no-args version of the method then you can use PowerMock to mock Calendar's getInstance method ([here's a question with examples of that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14456377/217324)).

Comment: This is the correct way of doing it.  +1.  You shouldn't be trying to test `Calendar.getInstance()` anyway, unless you work for Oracle, and you are developing a new version of it.  This is an excellent illustration of refactoring your code, to introduce a break between the parts that you _should_ be testing and the parts you shouldn't.  On another note, though, `getDate()` is a terrible name for these methods.